# SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Tags: mysql, hibernate, java, база-данных

Пишу на Java, использую Hibernate

Есть таблицы `Airplanes` (ключ - `aircraftKey`)
[image]

Есть таблица `Flights` (ключ - `flightKey`, внешний - `aircraftKey`)
[image]

Классы и xml файлы были созданы в eclipse с помощью hibernate tools

Для них было создано 2 класса и 2 hbm.xml файла

```
public class Aircrafts implements java.io.Serializable, Table {

    private Integer aircraftKey;
    private String model;
    private Integer passengerBc;
    private Integer passengerEc;
    private Set<Flights> flightses = new HashSet<>(0);

    // Constructors

    // Get/Set methods
}
```

Маппинг для Aircrafts

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 4, 2014 1:14:16 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping package="db.tables">
    <class name="Aircrafts" table="Aircrafts" catalog="Airplains">
        <id name="aircraftKey" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="aircraftKey" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="model" type="string">
            <column name="model" length="30" />
        </property>
        <property name="passengerBc" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="passengerBC" />
        </property>
        <property name="passengerEc" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="passengerEC" />
        </property>
        <set name="flightses" table="Flights" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="aircraftKey" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Flights" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Следующий класс

```
public class Flights implements java.io.Serializable, Table {

    private Integer flightKey;
    private Aircrafts aircrafts;
    private String from;
    private String where;
    private Date dateFlight;
    private Integer duration;
    private Boolean isTerminated;
    private Set<Prices> priceses = new HashSet<>(0); // есть ещё одна таблица, внешний ключ которой указывает на эту таблицу

    // Constructors

    // Get/Set methods

}
```

Маппинг для Flights

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 4, 2014 1:14:16 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping package="db.tables">
    <class name="Flights" table="Flights" catalog="Airplains">
        <id name="flightKey" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="flightKey" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="aircrafts" class="Aircrafts" fetch="select">
            <column name="aircraftKey" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="from" type="string">
            <column name="from" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="where" type="string">
            <column name="where" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateFlight" type="timestamp">
            <column name="dateFlight" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="duration" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="duration" />
        </property>
        <property name="isTerminated" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="isTerminated" />
        </property>
        <set name="priceses" table="Prices" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="flightKey" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Prices" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Дальше, вставляю в таблицу Flights запись:

```
Flights record = // create record
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

session.save(record); // Здесь вылет
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

Stack trace:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, where, dateFlight, duration, isTerminated) values (1, 'A', 'B', '2011-11-1' at line 1
Dec 07, 2014 6:19:37 PM menu.AddRecordMenuController add
SEVERE: null
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, where, dateFlight, duration, isTerminated) values (1, 'A', 'B', '2011-11-1' at line 1
...
```

Более того, смущает то что выше выдаёт дату '2011-11-1', хотя я использую:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm");
Date date = df.parse("11.11.11 11:11");
```

Так в чём же проблема?

Comment: from и where являются зарезервированными словами и не могут применяться для обозначения полей без экранирования. Как заставить hibernate экранировать - вопрос уже к нему.

Comment: Формат по-умолчанию:  
DATE - YYYY-MM-DD (от 1000-01-01 до 9999-12-31).  

DATETIME - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (от 1000-01-01 00:00:00 до 9999-12-31 23:59:59)

Comment: @smackmychi, да, реально нужно было маппинге Flights в строках применить знак '`':

<property name="from" type="string">
    <column name="`from`" length="20" not-null="true" />
</property>
<property name="where" type="string">
    <column name="`where`" length="20" not-null="true" />
</property>.

Отвечай на вопрос. Выберу его.

Comment: @vaddemgen раз разобрались, вопрос можно и закрыть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [здесь](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-use-database-reserved-keyword-in-hibernate/). Кстати, сам сайт вполне себе полезен примерами. Подозреваю, что можно было бы экранировать и с помощью "`".
Формат по-умолчанию:
DATE - YYYY-MM-DD (от 1000-01-01 до 9999-12-31).
DATETIME - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (от 1000-01-01 00:00:00 до 9999-12-31 23:59:59)